# React Native: I am using date time picker from community and it is converting my time to GMT+0

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native, mobile

I am on GMT+3 and when I use @react-native-community/datetimepicker. It converts my date automatically to the GMT+0. You can check my code below.
Do someone now why it is converting?
Thank you!

DATE TIME PICKER

```
 <DateTimePicker
   testID="dateTimePicker"
   value={data[name]} // value={new Date()}
   mode={type} // mode="time"
   is24Hour={true}
   display="spinner"
   onChange={handleChange}
   minimumDate={type === "date" ? new Date() : undefined}
 />
```

HANDLE CHANGE FUNCTION

```
const handleChange = (event: any, selectedDate: Date) => {
setShow(false)

console.log(selectedDate) // returns the selected date - 3 hours

if (selectedDate) {
  setDate(formatDate(selectedDate, type))
  setData({ ...data, [name]: selectedDate })
}
```

}

Comment: Check the timezone of the device, it takes the timezone from the device by default

Comment: I had it GMT+3.

Comment: Seems like a knows issue https://github.com/react-native-community/datetimepicker/issues/114

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I fixed it. I converted the time to the user device timezone by using a function before setDate.

UPDATE for the if from handleChange:

```
  setByTimezone(selectedDate)      
  setDate(formatDate(selectedDate, type))    
  setData({ ...data, [name]: selectedDate })
```

FUNCTION setByTimezone(this is the code for typescript, if someone with javascript want to use it, remove the  types):

```
const setByTimezone = (time: Date): void => {
  const date: Date = new Date()
  const difference: number = -date.getTimezoneOffset() / 60

  time.setHours(time.getHours() + difference)
}
```